# How to add IF condition in a WHILE loop

Tags: php, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make simple comments on posts. Adding comments I've successfully completed but I have a problem displaying them.
I use this code:

```
<?php
    require "config.php";
    $sql    = "SELECT post_id, user_id, comment FROM comments";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo  "User " .$row["user_id"]. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;add comment: ".$row["comment" ]."</br>";
        } 
    }
    else { echo "No comments for this post";}
?>
```

I must add a condition in the WHILE loop:

```
 if $row["post_id"]==$post_id
```

so comments are only displayed on posts for which they are written. ($post_id is defined previously). How can I do it?

Comment: You can just pass the post id in a `where` clause of your query instead

Comment: Thank you. I am a beginner in php, but I do not understand how I missed it

Answer (score 3):

1. As @midhat has pointed just use `where` clause of your query so if
   condition no longer required.
2. you can try this one

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if( $row["post_id"]==$post_id ){
          echo  "User " .$row["user_id"]. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;add comment:".$row["comment" ]."</br>";
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only fetch comments with specific `post_id` and don't need to apply any if condition as below:

```
<?php
    require "config.php";
    $sql    = "SELECT post_id, user_id, comment FROM comments where post_id = ".$post_id;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo  "User " .$row["user_id"]. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;add comment: ".$row["comment" ]."</br>";
        } 
    }
    else { echo "No comments for this post";}
?>
```

Hope it helps you.